# Stat test that allows comparing means across groups

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, multilevel-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset involving a dependent (numerical) variable and 2 indipendent (one nominal and the other numerical) variables. My nominal variable involves 4 groups, with each group being split into 20 parts representing years (the numerical variable). So, 10 samples for each year, 20 years for each 4 groups = 800 observations.

Is there a stat test that allows me to compare the means between years AND the 4 groups (and if they sig. differ) rather then either just the 4 groups, or the years on there own?

I want to test if there is a significant difference between the last years of each of the 4 groups.

Comment: You seem to be asking for ANOVA (ANalysis Of VAriance), specifically, two-way anova. See any introductory text, or search this site!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes after doing some research on the internet thats what I thought I should do. Actually, I did a Friedman's test in the end as my data was non-parametric. Thanks